# Why is my beam no propagating beyond the second mirror?

Tags: pstricks, pst-optexp

[image: Diagram with beam bending]

```
\documentclass[]{revtex4} 
\usepackage{pst-optexp}
\usepackage{pst-node}

\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}[showgrid=true](13,14)
\pnodes(2,10){A}(3,10){MIP}(3,12.5){LIP}(3,13){MIIP}(5,13){LIIP}
\pnodes(8,13){MIIIP}(8,8){MIVP}(14,8){LIIIP}(10,8){LIVP}(12,8){MVP}(12,3){d}
\pnodes(12,1){MVIP}(10,1){LVIP}(6,1){C}


\psset{mirrortype=extended, mirrordepth=0.2}


\begin{optexp}
    \optsource[innerlabel, compname = start](A)(MIP){Beam}
    \mirror[compname = mi, labelangle=45](A)(MIP)(LIP){$M_1$}
    \lens[compname = li, n=1.57](MIP)(LIP){$L_1$}

    \mirror[compname= mii, labelangle=-45](LIP)(MIIP)(LIIP){$M_{2}$}

    \lens[compname= lii, n=1.517](MIIP)(LIIP){$L_{2}$}

    \mirror[compname= miii, labelangle=-45](LIIP)(MIIIP)(MIVP){$M_{3}$}
    \mirror[compname= miv, labelangle=45](MIIIP)(MIVP)(LIIIP){$M_{4}$}

    \lens[compname= liii, n=1.517](MIVP)(LIIIP){$L_{3}$}

    \mirror[compname= mv, labelangle=-45](MIVP)(MVP)(d){$M_{5}$}
    \mirror[compname= mvi, labelangle=-45](d)(MVIP)(LVIP){$M_{6}$}


   \lens[compname= lensfour, n=1.517](MVIP)(LVIP){$L_{4}$}
   \optsource[innerlabel](C)(C){Comp.}
\end{optexp}
\addtopsstyle{Beam}{fillstyle=solid, fillcolor=green!20!white}
\drawwidebeam[beamwidth=0.4, beaminsidelast]{1-5}
\drawwidebeam[loadbeampoints]{5-12}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Do you also get an error `Error: /stackunderflow in --if-- ...` ?

Comment: I do not get that output.

Comment: Which compiler do you use? (I get the error when using `xelatex` to compile your code.)

Comment: that's the one I am using; I am a beginner though, so if there's a fix that doesn't require me to use xelatex, I am all ears!

Comment: Just to clarify: in my case, the compilation does not stop, I just get the error message when compiling with `xelatex`. I do not get an error when compiling with latex, and then converting to ps and then to pdf, but the rest of the beam does not show either. I have experience in this package whatsoever, but just from looking at your setup I could imagine that playing with the distances and/or overall scale may help.

Comment: ok, so I am using xelatex, but what I really want is to have a picture showing collimation; what did you do that I can do to make sure I get that output? what changes did you make to the script, or the compilation?

Comment: As I said, I did not solve your problem. And unfortunately I've never used this package before.

Answer (score 5):

**Debugging your setup**

`pst-optexp` offers you different debugging possibilities:

- Using `\psset{pswarning}` you can enable warnings at Postscript level. For your example you get "Warning pst-optexp: The upper beam missed an interface"
- By default `pst-optexp` respects the numerical aperture of the components. If one of the outer beams does not hit the next interface, the beam drawing stops. With `\psset{useNA=false}` you can disable this temporarily to see which beam goes wrong. For your setup the result is

[image]

You see, that the `M3`-mirror is too small (or the beam to wide) so the beam path is interrupted.

**Possible solution**

To tailor the beam to your needs, you can either fine-tune the refractive index `n` of all lenses, or you can draw the beam piecewise for the parallel and focusing parts, separately.

The recipe is as follows:

1. Draw the first parallel part with `\drawwidebeam[beamwidth=0.4, stopinside]{1-3}`, which traces the beam until the second interface of the first lens (draws only until the first interface.
2. Now draw the beam between the first and second lens with `\drawwidebeam[loadbeampoints, beamdiv=-20, stopinside]{3-5}`. This loads the end points of the previous `\drawwidebeam` call, but allows you to adjust the beam divergence.
3. From the second lens continue with `\drawwidebeam[loadbeampoints]` to again load the previous beam end points, but continue with parallel rays.

And so on.

```
\documentclass[pstricks,margin=12pt]{standalone} 
\usepackage{pst-optexp}

\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid=true](13,14)
\pnodes(2,10){A}(3,10){MIP}(3,12.5){LIP}(3,13){MIIP}(5,13){LIIP}
\pnodes(8,13){MIIIP}(8,8){MIVP}(14,8){LIIIP}(10,8){LIVP}(12,8){MVP}(12,3){d}
\pnodes(12,1){MVIP}(10,1){LVIP}(6,1){C}

\psset{mirrortype=extended, mirrordepth=0.2}
\psset{mirrorwidth=1.1}
\addtopsstyle{Beam}{fillstyle=solid, fillcolor=green!20!white}
\begin{optexp}
    \optsource[innerlabel, compname = start](A)(MIP){Beam}
    \mirror[compname = mi, labelangle=45](A)(MIP)(LIP){$M_1$}
    \lens[compname = li](MIP)(LIP){$L_1$}
    \drawwidebeam[beamwidth=0.4, stopinside]{1-3}

    \mirror[compname= mii, labelangle=-45](LIP)(MIIP)(LIIP){$M_{2}$}
    \lens[compname= lii](MIIP)(LIIP){$L_{2}$}
    \drawwidebeam[loadbeampoints, beamdiv=-20, stopinside]{3-5}

    \mirror[compname= miii, labelangle=-45](LIIP)(MIIIP)(MIVP){$M_{3}$}
    \mirror[compname= miv, labelangle=45](MIIIP)(MIVP)(LIIIP){$M_{4}$}

    \lens[compname= liii](MIVP)(LIIIP){$L_{3}$}
    \drawwidebeam[loadbeampoints, stopinside]{5-8}

    \mirror[compname= mv, labelangle=-45](MIVP)(MVP)(d){$M_{5}$}
    \mirror[compname= mvi, labelangle=-45](d)(MVIP)(LVIP){$M_{6}$}
    \lens[compname= lensfour](MVIP)(LVIP){$L_{4}$}
    \drawwidebeam[loadbeampoints, beamdiv=-6.3, stopinside]{8-11}
    \optbox[innerlabel](C)(C){Comp.}
    \drawwidebeam[loadbeampoints]{11}{12}
\end{optexp}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

BTW: Compiling `pst-optexp`-setups with `xelatex` doesn't work properly.

Comment: Thank you very much! How then can I adjust to make sure the aperture works?

Comment: Where exactly you make the adjustment? I tried adding it but I still get stuck at L2. More generally, how to make sure that doesn't happen, because I am working on a simple example, (same lenses, but horizontally next to each other) and my beam still gets stuck on l2!

Comment: That image is done only by adding `\psset{useNA=false}`, without any adjustments, yet. But this mode allows you to better see what goes wrong.